# jQuery navbar mouse hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

there is a sidebar that i created with jquery. when i hover mouse fast on the sidebar then on "red" area the 3th item has to open a submenu but it dosen't; 
how can i fix it?

[this is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kalagar/c4vsa7j4/13/) with css! but it dosent work at all over there !!

i use my own css and jquery 1.11.0

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $('ul.insidenav > li').hover(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('ul.insidenavsubmenu').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('ul.insidenavsubmenu').stop(true).slideDown('1000');
      $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
    }
  }, function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul.insidenavsubmenu').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('ul.insidenavsubmenu').stop(true).slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    }
  });
});

jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $('ul.insidenavsubmenu > li').hover(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('ul.dubinsidenavsubmenu').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('ul.dubinsidenavsubmenu').stop(true).slideDown('1000');
      $(this).addClass('arrow-down');
    }
  }, function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul.dubinsidenavsubmenu').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('ul.dubinsidenavsubmenu').stop(true).slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass('arrow-down');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="insidenav">
      <li class="purple">
        <a href="" class="link purple"><span>ابر پژوهیار</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;" class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a href="">کتابخانه من</a>
          </li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="">اطلاعات کاربر</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">مشخصات کاربر</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">اطلاعات حساب</a>
          </li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="">تغیر کلمه عبور</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">خروج</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="green">
        <a href="" class="link green">
          <span>فراداده‌های موضوعی</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="blue">
        <a href="" class="link blue">
          <span>استناددهی آنلاین</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="darkorange">
        <a class="link darkorange"><span>دانشنامه استناددهی</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;" class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a href="">همزمان‌سازی</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">شیوه نگارش مقاله</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">شیوه نگارش پایان نامه</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">استناددهی</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">بیشتر بدانیم...</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">مثال های استناددهی</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="orange">
        <a href="" class="link orange"><span>خرید آنلاین</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;" class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="">خرید و دریافت پستی</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">خرید و دریافت آنلاین</a>
          </li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="">خرید «پژوهیار» از دیجی‌کالا</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="red">
        <a class="link red"><span>کارگاه‌های آموزشی</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;" class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a href="">کارگاه‌های آموزشی برگزار شده</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">شرایط کارگاه‌های آموزشی</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>ثبت نام</a>
            <ul class="dubinsidenavsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">فرم ثبت نام تربیت مدرس</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">فرم ثبت نام کارگاه سازمانی</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">فرم ثبت نام کارگاه عمومی</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="lightgreen">
        <a class="link lightgreen"><span>شبکه مدرسان</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;" class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a href="">استان‌های فعال</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">رزومه مدرسان</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">شرایط جذب مدرس</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="darkbrown">
        <a class="link darkbrown"><span>سفارشی‌سازی</span></a>
        <ul class="insidenavsubmenu">
          <li><a href="">درج شیوه‌نامه در نرم‌افزار</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
                            حمایت از وبگاه‌ها
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
                            درج کتابخانه موضوعی                                     
                        </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, all you need to do is to load your custom script at the end of the body to ensure all elements you are trying to attach event handlers to are loaded before the events are attached.
To check that change the JSFiddle javascript settings of load type to "No wrap - in body"

**EDIT:** Also for some reason your specifying selector `$('ul.insidenav > li')` is not working. if you use generalizing  one from CSS1.0 `$('ul.insidenav li')` i works fine.

If we look at the W3Schools documentation on CSS selectors we can find a Note for the `ul.insidenav > li` selector that states that:

> Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.

This may be the cause of the problem, since the general `ul.insidenav li` works just fine.
Reference to the entire CSS selectors documentation you may find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: thank you. bu my question is why in the red area the 3th item submenu wont work after i hover my mouse fast over the sidebar?
i did this suggestion but still not working !!!

Comment: I have found an issue with the selector you are using, i have updated my answer with a solution that fixes your problem and your code starts working properly. If you would like me to explain why the specifying selector dose not work let me know, so could investigate it further. Hope this was helpful to you

Comment: what is have to do? i fixed `ul.insidenav > li` but still not working !!

Comment: I did make it work, sadly i'm not able to update your JSFiddle for some unknown reason and provide you with a working sample. So all you need to do is to FIRST: put the script at the END of the BODY, SECOND: use a local Jquery not a CDN one to be sure that its always loaded in the HEAD of the page. THIRD CHANGE THE SELECTOR as i explained

Comment: thank you Veladimir. i make it work. i use finish() function Instead of stop() and it worked !!! thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would try wrapping all the code in $(document).ready, just to make sure that all of the document is loaded (though I'd advise doing what Vladimir suggests, as well :) )

Take a look here:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Edit: first of all, move all ready functions to one ready function ( `$(document).ready` or `$(function () {...})` ) and move all event click binds into this function.

Comment: Checking your fiddle (though it does bother me that you have multiple ready functions...), but I notice that this line `$('.trick-rate input').rating();` fails with `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function`, which prevents the rest of the function to execute. Does it happen for you, too, or is it just me?

Comment: Check the edit - this better happen first of all, and then check (maybe with console logs or debuggers) that everything executes and nothing throws.